# Does the dupe-hammer break the grace period?

Tags: support, dupehammer, grace-period

Today I hammered a question, the initial version of which was

[image: initial version]

It took me a minute to find the appropriate duplicate and close it. After 5 more minutes the OP pinged me and requested me to reopen their question. The question looked [very differently](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41511267/1), and it was obvious that the OP had edited it during the grace period: the edit history link was hidden and the timeline contained no relevant events.

Apparently, the *"Possible duplicate"* comment (that is automatically added even when a question is being closed as duplicate by a single user) failed to break the grace period, in which case the user had 4 more minutes to make his edit before the grace period ended. ([reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/21789/260312)) Of course, the OP could have edited the question *before* I closed it, however I did not receive the standard *"an edit has been made to this post"* notification.

Can anyone explain what exactly happened here? Does Mjölnir terminate the grace period?

Comment: With how quickly the comment gets deleted with the hammer... I wonder if it's a case of the comment not triggering the new revision, or if it's a case of the comment having to be undeleted to break the grace period...

Comment: what @Kendra writes makes sense to me, I think I already experienced it that comments I quickly self-delete don't break grace period

Comment: Comments that are deleted before the edit is made do not count against the grace period IIRC.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As Tiny noted, comments only end the grace period *if they're visible when the next revision is submitted*.

Since the duplicate comment is *instantly deleted* when the vote is binding, closing as a duplicate won't end the grace period by itself; you'd have to leave another comment. This also implies that even a pre-existing duplicate comment would not end the grace period if the question was closed before being edited, since it would be deleted at the time of closure.

Same thing applies to answers; I've updated the FAQ to make this explicit.

Comment: Feature request: closure should end the grace period.

Comment: That... was unexpected, since the closing alters the post history/revision. I would have expected to clear the grace period.

Comment: I assume this also result in the edit not adding the question to the reopen queue.