# Closure should end the grace period for edits

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, closed-questions, grace-period

[As explained by Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/341060/1529630):

> comments only end the grace period if they're visible when the next
>   revision is submitted.

[But as stated by Braiam](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/341050/1529630#comment429508_341060):

> That... was unexpected, since the closing alters the post
>   history/revision. I would have expected to clear the grace period

[So I propose](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/341050/1529630#comment429419_341060):

> Feature request: closure should end the grace period.

Comment: So glad you posted this. I meant to do it after reading Shog9's answer, but then got busy doing something else and forgot. Although I'm a bit concerned that Shog took the time to update the FAQ, rather than update the code, implying that he thinks this is by design.

Comment: @CodyGray Because code isn't so easy to change compared to free text in an FAQ perhaps?

Comment: Why not close *votes* to end the grace period? Or any significant interaction with the post?

Comment: @AndrasDeak Closing alters the post history. Close votes don't, so it's less obvious they should end the grace period. If this weaker proposal gets accepted, you can request additional restrictions.

Comment: While that may be true, @David, in my experience, you don't incorporate information about bugs into the FAQ. At least, not bugs that you plan on fixing!

Comment: This might need to be a request on Meta.SE instead, as this isn't specific to SO. The [prior grace period change was due to Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216567/reset-question-grace-period-once-an-answer-has-been-posted)

Comment: @Machavity I believe you can post any bug/feature-request/support/etc.. on any site you wish

Comment: So should flags.

Answer (score 25):

This has been implemented; I can turn it on at some point after the next build (so whenever the number bottom-left says something higher than rev 2017.3.29.25552)

**Update:** Enabled everywhere as of April 3rd, 2017.

Comment: inb4 now questions [ain't closing anymore](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/345362/7920660)

Comment: @Shog Why features that affect the whole network are announced only on a per-site meta? What we have Meta Stack Exchange for exactly? (i.e. such requests should be migrated to MSE, or MSE can be shut down and MSO will be the central meta site, like it used to be in the past.)

Comment: I updated the guidance in two different places on MSE when this went live, @Shadow. I didn't post a big announcement because this is pretty obscure; arguably the best reason for implementing it was that folks *assumed it already worked this way*.

Comment: @Shog9 I see. Still, why not migrate to MSE?