# Migrated question has six close votes but is not closed

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, migrated-questions

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42742207/how-to-reload-the-data-from-my-database-to-my-chat-application

Also, when I voted to close it the close dialogue errored but it still recorded my close vote. And no, I don't know what the error was.

Comment: "-1 more votes are needed." There's our problem.

Comment: Huh. That question is all sorts of messed up. Aside from the close votes not working: It doesn't include any of the usual information about the migration, and the OP's delete vote didn't delete the question either. I'd guess the migration rejection mechanism is busted which is preventing the close/delete mechanisms from firing properly.

Comment: Has 10 cv's now.

Comment: When I cast the 10th close vote, it said an error had occurred, but the vote still counted.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Same and then I refreshed and it did record the vote.  Has 12 CV's now

Comment: @approxiblue You're right. The help center says [*"It takes 5 close votes"*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) so 5 people need to take their vote back.

Comment: Well, looks like locking it still works.

Comment: Now that it is locked, it can no longer be reproduced :(

Comment: [This other post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42742199) (also migrated from Super User) has the same problem.

Comment: Looks like there should be a comparison for `>=` for the CVs, not equality.

Comment: @Olaf The main issue here is that the question managed to get past 5 CVs in the first place.

Comment: @NobodyNada: Sure, maybe it's some race-condition during migration? (I sometimes love such pure speculation:-)

Comment: As reported by NobodyNada, [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42742199/edit-tools-use-turnjs) is up to [20 close votes now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZLsC.png) with no upper limit in sight. Interestingly, that means that 20 of the 30 people to view the question voted to close.

Comment: A [search for migrated questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=migrated%3ayes) will, of course, show others which are, probably, on their way to having the same problem.

Comment: @Makyen: and moderators can't close these posts either, nor can we delete them. They are well b0rken.

Comment: @Makyen: not all migrated posts are affected, I was able to close one of the posts in your search just fine. Looks like there are more variables at play here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Had that post gotten over 5 close votes? I wouldn't be surprised if the moderators can't close issue only occurs once the number of close votes is > 5 (maybe >=5). In other words, one bug cascading into another, due to unanticipated values.

Comment: @Makyen: it did not have that many close votes yet, no. Perhaps that's it. I can't quite see what animuson meant about migration data missing; they can see more than I can, I can't tell if that other post is as messed up as the first.

Comment: I knew that Stack Exchange management is [unhappy about migration policy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342440/839601) lately but didn't expect that things will come that far. What was migrated should stay no matter what, no rejections allowed, wow

Comment: "Then shalt thou count to five close votes, no more, no less. Five shall be the number thou shalt count to, and the number of the counting shall be five..." Six is, of course, right out.

Comment: There's definitely something smelly about migrated posts. [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42767959/what-is-the-argument-xi-of-zip-doing) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42759281/how-can-i-kill-the-parent-shell-script-process-without-killing-child-process) are even throwing 500 server errors!

Comment: Looks like it's fixed: `put on hold as too broad by AbcAeffchen, VDWWD, Archer, Rob, Syden, tom redfern, Keiwan, Louis, QPaysTaxes, Alexander O'Mara, eldarerathis, NathanOliver, Rizier123, Ryan♦, Jeremy Banks♦, animuson♦ 2 mins ago`

Comment: @animuson no funny history about how Nick Craver messed up?

Comment: This other question has 28 close votes (screenshot of deleted question) https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/345387