# More than 5 close votes on question

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, migrated-questions

There is a bug on this particular question, as it has 15 close votes at time of post. Bug seems like it was caused by the question migration.

**https://stackoverflow.com/q/42742199**

Found via Close Votes queue https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/15511959

**Please do not vote to close**, your vote will be wasted as it doesn't close!

[image]

---

## Update:

Bug is now resolved. We have a record of **28** close votes on a single question!

[image]